# My chart keeps resizing when I redraw it. How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django-templates, chart.js

Note: This is using the chart.js library inside a Django template
I am creating a doughnut graph (see image 0) with some data. Then, I destroy the instance of that chart and redraw it (see image 1). The graph in image 1 and image 0 have the same data, however, image 1's graph is much larger and shifted to the right. In fact, when I try to redraw the chart using different data, the chart also gets bigger and shifts to the right making the legend be cut off. How do I stop this? I have provided the code of the graph's below.
[Graph 0: Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZtQ2.png)
[Graph 1: New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJvP.png)

This is the code for the first graph.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-4">
    <div class="col-span-0 w-full rounded-xl p-4" style="height: 400px; width: 50%;">
        <h5 class="text-gray-500" id="chart_revenue_title">Custom Title</h5>
        <canvas id="chart_revenue_id"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        let canvas_revenue = document.getElementById("chart_revenue_id")
        ctx_revenue = canvas_revenue.getContext("2d");
        let chart_revenue = new Chart(ctx_revenue, {
            type: "doughnut",
            data: {
                labels: [
                    {% for project in all_projects %}
                        ['{{project.name}}', '{{project.client.name}}', '{{project.id}}'],
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Revenue",
                    data: [
                        {% for project in all_projects %}
                            {{project.total_cost}},
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    hoverOffset: 4
                }]
            },
            options: {
                animation: {
                    animateRotate: true,
                    animateScale: true,
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: "easeOutQuart"
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: ["Revenue Distribution", "Total Revenue: ${{total_revenue}}", "Total Clients: {{total_clients}}"],
                        align: 'center',
                        padding: {
                            top: 0,
                            bottom: 20
                        },
                        font: {
                            size: 18,
                            weight: "bold"
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        labels: {
                            font: {
                            size: 12
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: [{
                // Callback after the chart has been drawn
                beforeInit: function(chart,options) {
                    // Get the dynamically generated title text
                    let titleText = chart.options.plugins.title.text;
                    // Update the inner HTML of the h2 element with the generated title
                    document.getElementById('chart_revenue_title').innerHTML = titleText.join('<br>') +'<br> ';
                }
            }]
        });
        canvas_revenue.onclick = (evt) => {
            const res_doughnut = chart_revenue.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
            if (res_doughnut.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            let url = "{% url 'project-dashboard:project_summary' pk=0 %}".replace(/0/, chart_revenue.data.labels[res_doughnut[0].index][2].toString());
            document.location.href = url;     
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

This is the code for the destruction and redrawing of the first graph.
Note: This is within an ajax request that gets some data asynchronously.

```
//recreating the doughnut chart
chart_revenue.destroy();
var project_stats = data['project_stats']

const label_stats = []
const data_stats = []
project_stats.forEach(stat_function)
function stat_function(x){
    label_stats.push([x[0], x[1], x[2]])
    data_stats.push(x[3])
}

chart_revenue = new Chart(ctx_revenue, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
        labels: label_stats,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Revenue",
            data: data_stats,
            hoverOffset: 4
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: true,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeOutQuart"
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            title: {
            display: false,
            text: ["Revenue Distribution", "Total Revenue: $" + data['total_revenue'], "Total Clients: " + data['total_clients']],
            align: 'center',
            padding: {
                top: 0,
                bottom: 20
            },
            font: {
                size: 18,
                weight: "bold"
            }
            },
            legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "right",
            labels: {
                font: {
                size: 12
                }
            }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [{
        // Callback after the chart has been drawn
        beforeInit: function(chart,options) {
            // Get the dynamically generated title text
            let titleText = chart.options.plugins.title.text;
            // Update the inner HTML of the h2 element with the generated title
            document.getElementById('chart_revenue_title').innerHTML = titleText.join('<br>') + '<br> ';
        }
    }]
});
```

I tried looking at redrawing the chart but it seems to be fine. I also thought it perhaps because the ajax request is contained within a different  element, but I am drawing the chart through the original canvas element so I do not think that is the issue. None of these fixed the problem. I don't really know where the issue is.

Comment: I think the canvas measurements interact with those of the `h5` element, which is dynamic. Quick (possible) fix: include the `canvas` element in a `div` with no attributes; check this [note in docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) for responsive charts. Debugging tip: in development, set each element's (`div`s, `h5`, `canvas`) to something like `background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.7)` so you can see the computed size of each element and/or check those size in dev tools.

Comment: Also, I have to remind you that the recommended approach is to [update](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) the chart, not to destroy and recreate it; in my experience the latter is almost never required since the update can completely change the chart in all its properties

Comment: @kikon Oh. I thought I was supposed to destroy the chart since sometimes I repopulate it with completely different datasets. Could you explain the quick fix a little more? what does it mean to include the `canvas` element in a `div` with no attributes?

Comment: Well, I hoped you would test it first and let me know if it works for you; I tested with a version that has several differences from yours. If not, we'll have to add a `height` or `min-height` style to that div. Since `canvas` is an inline element, the size of the canvas for a  responsive chart is connected to that of its parent (div); I'll elaborate on that if we find a solution that works for the destroy/recreate scenario

Comment: unfortunately putting the `canvas` element in a `div` tag with no elements does not work (it makes the chart go haywire). Also, there is another chart next to the doughnut chart that has essentially the same format in terms of the canvas, but it has no issues with the resizing.

Comment: I think this needs debugging. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-paper-forked-29k9fk) with the code I made to test your version; and [this](https://29k9fk.csb.app/) is the page preview. Maybe you could try to do something similar that could be debugged. By trying to make the second chart mach yours as much as possible I see that if there are 13 items in the doughnut, it is possible that the legend overflows.